# Report Builder 3.0 - How to get the name (not the label) of a parameter

Tags: sql, vba, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I know that I can get the value (`Parameters!parm.Value -> 1`) and the label (`Parameters!parm.Label -> "ParmLabel"`), but how do I get the name of the parameter (`??? -> "parm"`)?

Comment: You are supplying the parameter name in the expression so why are you trying to return it?

Comment: It seems you are trying to do something dynamic with parameters where you don’t know their names ahead of time? Can you expand upon that use case more?

Comment: @thomas yep, pretty much. Given any report, I need to be able to get the names of all UI parms. I'll also need to be able to associate the names of the parms with the values that the user selected when they hit "View Report".

Comment: I would imagine you will have to do this in Custom Code within the report. Are you looking to do this in some other language or location? Seems like if you have access to all the reports to add Custom Code then you already know the answer to which parameters exist.

Comment: I do have access to all the reports and yes I can add custom code, but I don't have the time to write out very specific code for each report. I need something generic that captures the parm names in any report.

Comment: Let's start there - how would I write custom code to get the list of parm names?

Comment: I see you posted another question on the same topic. I think that other question may answer this one as well.